# Firebase (Android): Transaction.success(mutableData) causes app to crash

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write a function to increment unread message count in a chatapp(android) using transaction in Firebase.

My database structure looks like:

The member list can in fact contain more than 2 users for a group chat which I intend to expand later.

[image]

Currently, messages can be added into the messageList but after adding to the messageList I want to increase the unreadCount for all other user except the sender as well. I realised that I need to make use of Transaction to make it atomic so this is my incrementUnreadCount code.

```
private static void incrementUnreadCount(String chatRoomId) {

    DatabaseReference mDatabaseMemberList = mDatabaseChatRooms.child(chatRoomId).child("memberList");

    mDatabaseMemberList.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

            Map<String, Map<String, Object>> tempMemberList = (Map<String, Map<String, Object>>) mutableData.getValue();

            if (tempMemberList == null) {
                return Transaction.abort();
            }

            for (String key : tempMemberList.keySet()) {
                // if it is not a sender node
                if (!key.equals(TutUserManager.getCurrentUid())) {
                    Map<String, Object> tempMap = tempMemberList.get(key);
                    long tempCount = (long) tempMap.get("unreadCount");
                    tempCount += 1;
                    tempMap.put("unreadCount", tempCount);
                    tempMemberList.put(key, tempMap);
                }
            }

            mutableData.setValue(tempMemberList);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
    });
}
```

The following code works only when I send the second message. So the value of unreadCount is 1 less than what it is expected to be.

I read the doc and realised that for the null case it is supposed to be:

```
return Transaction.success(mutableData);
```

and not:

```
return Transaction.abort();
```

as abort() will make server abort the transaction instead of trying to make the transaction again.

I try to change the code above to use `return ransaction.success(mutableData);` but it causes the app to crash upon calling the function.

Did I miss something ?

This is what I get from the console:

```
11/14 23:19:25: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Users\Potcharaphol\AndroidStudioProjects\Tut\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.pchatanan.tut
$ adb shell am start -n "com.pchatanan.tut/com.pchatanan.tut.MainActivities.GetStartedActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.pchatanan.tut.test | com.pchatanan.tut
Connecting to com.pchatanan.tut
E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1339)
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.pchatanan.tut, real application class is null.

              [ 11-14 23:19:29.241  2931: 2931 E/         ]
              process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

                  [ 11-14 23:19:29.819  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                  process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9877
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
        adb shell setprop firebase.analytics.debug-mode com.pchatanan.tut
I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustAlarmManagerImpl
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

       [ 11-14 23:19:30.422  2931: 2931 E/         ]
       process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 4
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/n/arm64-v8a

          [ 11-14 23:19:31.068  2931: 2931 E/         ]
          process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false

          [ 11-14 23:19:33.493  2931: 2931 E/         ]
          process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false

          [ 11-14 23:19:35.396  2931: 2931 E/         ]
          process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.466ms
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20588 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

This is what I get from logcat, there seems to be no errors.

```
                                                               [ 11-14 23:21:49.129  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                               process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:21:49.321 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 23:21:49.522 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 23:21:49.723 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

                                                               [ 11-14 23:21:49.781  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                               process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:21:49.924 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 23:21:50.125 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/System.out: debugger has settled (1319)
11-14 23:21:50.149 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.pchatanan.tut, real application class is null.

                                                               [ 11-14 23:21:50.364  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                               process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:21:50.842 21571-21633/com.pchatanan.tut W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-14 23:21:50.863 21571-21633/com.pchatanan.tut W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-14 23:21:50.973 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9877
11-14 23:21:50.973 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
11-14 23:21:50.980 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                         adb shell setprop firebase.analytics.debug-mode com.pchatanan.tut

                                                       [ 11-14 23:21:50.999  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                       process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:21:51.035 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustAlarmManagerImpl
11-14 23:21:51.043 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
11-14 23:21:51.140 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
11-14 23:21:51.216 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-14 23:21:51.601 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.

                                                                          [ 11-14 23:21:51.609  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                                          process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:21:51.875 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:21:51.925 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
11-14 23:21:52.015 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4
11-14 23:21:52.015 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 4
11-14 23:21:52.030 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/n/arm64-v8a
11-14 23:21:52.192 21571-21651/com.pchatanan.tut E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-14 23:21:52.193 21571-21651/com.pchatanan.tut I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-14 23:21:52.194 21571-21666/com.pchatanan.tut I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false

                                                           [ 11-14 23:21:52.196  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                           process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:21:54.257 21571-21711/com.pchatanan.tut I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false

                                                           [ 11-14 23:21:54.586  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                           process stopped due to unexpected signal 13


                                                           [ 11-14 23:21:55.208  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                           process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:21:56.193 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
11-14 23:21:56.248 21571-21743/com.pchatanan.tut I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
11-14 23:21:56.279 21571-21743/com.pchatanan.tut I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false

                                                           [ 11-14 23:21:56.442  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                           process stopped due to unexpected signal 13


                                                           [ 11-14 23:21:57.081  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                           process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:21:57.204 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:21:57.206 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:01.561 21571-21633/com.pchatanan.tut W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

                                                                   [ 11-14 23:22:01.587  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                                   process stopped due to unexpected signal 13


                                                                   [ 11-14 23:22:02.195  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                                   process stopped due to unexpected signal 13


                                                                   [ 11-14 23:22:02.874  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                                   process stopped due to unexpected signal 13


                                                                   [ 11-14 23:22:03.487  2931: 2931 E/         ]
                                                                   process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
11-14 23:22:07.605 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:07.720 21571-21641/com.pchatanan.tut I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
11-14 23:22:07.775 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
11-14 23:22:07.985 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:07.985 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:09.062 21571-21942/com.pchatanan.tut I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
11-14 23:22:09.141 21571-21942/com.pchatanan.tut I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
11-14 23:22:09.354 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
11-14 23:22:09.454 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
11-14 23:22:09.471 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:09.472 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:09.476 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
11-14 23:22:10.246 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:10.308 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:10.309 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:10.313 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 23:22:13.747 21571-21571/com.pchatanan.tut I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21571 SIG: 9
11-14 23:22:13.995 22048-22063/com.pchatanan.tut E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-14 23:22:14.012 22048-22048/com.pchatanan.tut I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.pchatanan.tut, real application class is null.
11-14 23:22:14.575 22048-22083/com.pchatanan.tut W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-14 23:22:14.659 22086-22100/com.pchatanan.tut E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-14 23:22:14.679 22086-22086/com.pchatanan.tut I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.pchatanan.tut, real application class is null.
11-14 23:22:15.323 22086-22133/com.pchatanan.tut W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-14 23:22:15.341 22086-22133/com.pchatanan.tut W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-14 23:22:15.462 22086-22086/com.pchatanan.tut I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9877
11-14 23:22:15.462 22086-22086/com.pchatanan.tut I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
11-14 23:22:15.471 22086-22086/com.pchatanan.tut I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                         adb shell setprop firebase.analytics.debug-mode com.pchatanan.tut
11-14 23:22:15.524 22086-22086/com.pchatanan.tut I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustAlarmManagerImpl
11-14 23:22:15.532 22086-22086/com.pchatanan.tut I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
11-14 23:22:25.611 22086-22133/com.pchatanan.tut W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: Post the stack trace for the crash.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a newbie here. How do I simply get a stack trace for the crash ?

Comment: If you are running from Android Studio, it will be in the _Android Monitor_ window, logcat pane.

Comment: I have editted the post but I don't think that helps much. Basically, when I use `Transaction.abort()` it works, if I use `Transaction.success(mutableData)` then app crashed.

Comment: I don't see why it would crash.  What you are doing is basically the same as what is shown as an [example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).  Are you sure all you do to cause the crash is change the one line?

Comment: Yes it's that one line that make the app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of iterate through each node in the Transaction thread, I use `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and iterate through each node. Then for the one that needs to be updated, I run the transaction code. This method works fine.

This is illustrated in the following code:

```
private static void incrementUnreadCount(String chatRoomId) {

        final DatabaseReference mDatabaseMemberList = mDatabaseChatRooms.child(chatRoomId).child("memberList");

        mDatabaseMemberList.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(!child.getKey().equals(TutUserManager.getCurrentUid())){

                        mDatabaseMemberList.child(child.getKey()).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                            @Override
                            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

                                Map<String, Object> tempData = (Map<String, Object>) mutableData.getValue();
                                if(tempData == null){
                                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                }
                                long unreadCount = (long) tempData.get("unreadCount");
                                unreadCount += 1;
                                tempData.put("unreadCount", unreadCount);
                                mutableData.setValue(tempData);
                                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```